# What is the total number of qubits required for the Harrow-Hassidim-Lloyd algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

I am fairly new to Quantum Computing and I know a bit of Linear Algebra. I am currently working on the [HHL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations) algorithm, I'm having confusion as to how many qubits are actually required in the circuit for an $(N \times N) $ coefficient matrix $A$. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  You say you are familiar with linear algebra - great!  Can you revise your posting to indicate what you know or what you expect to be the answer? Right now your question is pretty broad.  For example, relative to $N$ do you know how many qubits are used to store input vector $\vec b$ as an input register $|b\rangle$, and similarly the number of qubits in your output register $|x\rangle$?